# mySQL - return best results

Tags: mysql

I want to have a query that returns the best results from a table.

I am defining the best results to be the addition of two columns a + b (each column holds an int)

ie:

```
entry   a    b
1       4    5
2       3    2
3      20    30
```

Entry 3 would be returned because a + b is the highest in this case.

Is there a way to do this?  One idea I had was to create another column in the table which holds the addition of a and b and then ORDER by DESC, but that seems a little bit messy.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        a + b DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Adding another column, however, would be a good option, since you could index this column which would improve the query.

Comment: An interesting option would be to have a column `a` and a column `a+b` but not a `b` column. You would then retrieve `b` by `a+b - a` and have no redundancy. Would there be any major implications of this?

Comment: @lasseespeholt: the implications would be impossibility to create an index on `b` should the @op need one.